# How to get and compare the elements of the jsonb array in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Postgres 9.6.1

```
    CREATE TABLE "public"."test" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "packet" jsonb,
    )
    WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
    ;
```

Jsonb

```
    {"1": {"end": 14876555, "quantity":10}, "2": {"end": 14876555, "quantity":10} }
```

or

```
    [{"op": 1, "end": 14876555, "quantity": 10}, {"op": 2, "end": 14876555, "quantity": 20}]
```

All attempts to retrieve an array results in an error:
cannot extract elements from an object

It is necessary to compare all the elements "end" < 1490000 and find the id.

"op": 1 or "1": variable value and the full path is not suitable for solutions

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Show better the example. Probably, if I had not tried various options, then here I would not write. For example: select packet->>'end' from json_array_elements('[{"op": 3, "end": 14876555, "quantity": 10}, {"op": 4, "end": 14876556, "quantity": 10}]') as packet where (packet->>'end')::int > 14876555 This works, but if a data table 9.6.1 is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no the agreed JSON structure the best solution IMO is something like

```
select *
from
  public.test,
  regexp_matches(packet::text, '"end":\s*(\d+)', 'g') as e(x)
where
  x[1]::numeric < 1490000;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, some tables can grow significantly. Search json not very fast, regexp will be even slower. I did not think that a dynamic paths such problems. Examples for earlier versions I have not earned, and therefore I ask to see a working example.

Comment: @NestorUzhvij Is it what you ask: `select x, y, '{"a": ["b","c"]}'::jsonb->x->y from (values('a',0)) as t(x,y);`? However read this: [PostgreSQL anti-patterns: Unnecessary json/hstore dynamic columns](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/)

Comment: Thank you. The article helped :)

Comment: @NestorUzhvij BTW if you **really** need to use JSON data then look at the [plpythonu](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html)